# Toda DIV tem posição relativa?

Tags: html, css

Ouvi de um profissional da área de desenvolvimento que:

> "Toda `div` é relativa, mesmo sem você definir `position:relative`"

Isso está correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, pois quando você aplica:

```
div{
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
}
```

a `div` não aparenta mudança,enquanto que em:

```
div{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
}
```

é perceptível.

Answer (score 11):

Errado, no HTML a `position` por defeito (by default) é `position: static;`

Referência: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position)

Comment: como assim por defeito?

Comment: @Kazzkiq Quando não defines a `position`, o valor assumido pelo *browser* é `static` para a uma `div`.

Comment: A sim, o valor **padrão**. É que a palavra "defeito" não é muito utilizada no Brasil para traduzir "default". Não sabia que "defeito" também pode ser utilizado com o mesmo significado na língua portuguesa, interessante. :)

Comment: @JorgeB. sugeriria editar por ao menos "defeito/default" ou "padrão" no lugar, assim os comments poderiam ser deletados. Acho legal não interferir na questão cultural, mas por azar, esta palavra tem um sentido bem diferente no Brasil. (depois deleto esse comment aqui tambem)

Answer (score 3):

A posição padrão é `static` para qualquer elemento HTML,  se não for especificado explicitamente

`position: static;`

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/xTrdL/)**