# Qual o método padrão de posicionamento dos elementos numa página?

Tags: html, css

Qual o método padrão de posicionamento dos elementos numa página?

Pergunto porque já havia visto em alguma material que por padrão os elementos numa página (`HTML`) têm a propriedade `position` definida como `relative`, porém pesquisando não encontro um material a confirmar esta tese (dei uma olhada no [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) e nada).

Comment: respondendo a pergunta com humor.... um em baixo do outro preferencialmente

Comment: Não captei o seu comentário @Otto

Comment: o metodo padrão para posicionamento dos elementos é um em baixo do outro .... preferencialmente com identação

Comment: @Cold é complicado esse negócio de padrão, melhor é forçar o relative "manualmente" pra evitar os absolute de dentro ficarem perdidos pela página.

Comment: Então se eu colocar duas `div's`, com larguras de `10px` cada, e visualizar numa tela de 17 polegadas por exemplo (janela maximizada mesmo), ele vai colocar um embaixo do outro?

Comment: @Bacco eu também prefiro "reforçar", mas normalmente ele se comporta como `relative` pelas observações que fiz.

Comment: facepalm..... esquece meus comentários estava zuando

Comment: Na boa @Otto, depois de perceber até deu pa rir mano. :D

Comment: @cold experimente inserir 3 divs de tamanhos diferentes e um elemento absolute dentro do último, que vc vai ver que o padrão não é relative :)

Comment: Só para reforçar algo que é pregado na [gringa](http://www.w3fools.com/) e que eu concordo fortemente: Evite links para W3S. O conteúdo deles é muito fraco. Prefira linkar a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) :)

Comment: Possível duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23532/toda-div-tem-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-relativa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O metodo padrão é `static`, que posiciona o elemento por ordem de aparecimento.

Os outros métodos são:

- **absolute**: Posiciona o elemento de acordo com um ancestral definido com a propriedade **relative**
- **fixed**: Posiciona o elemento relativo a "tela".
- **relative**: A diferênça entre este método e o `static` é que você pode usar os propriedades `left, top`.
- **initial**: Aponta pro valor inicial da propriedade, no caso `static`
- **inherit**: Define como a mesma propriedade do elemento pai.

---

**Fonte: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)**

Comment: obrigado (por me mostrar o que não havia reparado). :D