# Qual é o valor padrão para o atributo "position"?

Tags: css

No CSS, sei que a propriedade `position` pode receber os valores `fixed`, `absolute` e `relative` . Cada uma tem um efeito diferente sobre a posição do elemento.

Porém fiquei na dúvida quando fui questionado da seguinte forma por outro programador:

*"Se eu possuir um elemento com `fixed`, `absolute` ou `relative` e quiser resetar para o valor que vem por padrão no CSS, qual seria o valor de eu tenho que definir `position`?"*.

Então gostaria de tirar essa dúvida: Qual é o valor padrão da propriedade `position`?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Toda Div tem posição relativa?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23532/toda-div-tem-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-relativa/23534#23534)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O valor por defeito (por padrão) é `static` para qualquer elemento HTML que não tenha o `position` especificado

```
position: static;
```

Assim como explicado em https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#position-property

Answer (score 6):

O valor por defeito (por padrão) é `static`.

Está referido na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) e [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#position-property):

> **position**
>   **Value:**     static | relative | absolute | fixed | inherit
>   **Initial:**   static